# MySQL many-to-many join Having AND query not working

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, having

I have the following five tables:

```
 company        type    branch      company_type       company_branch
 -------        ----    ------     -------------       --------------
  c_id          t_id     b_id       c_id | t_id         c_id | b_id     
  ----          ---      ----       -----------        --------------
   1             1        1            1  1              1     1
   2             2        2            1  2              1     2
                 3        3            2  1              2     1
                                       2  3              2     3
```

The following two queries work fine:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`c_id`
FROM (`company` co)
JOIN `company_type` t ON `t`.`c_id` = `co`.`c_id`
WHERE `co`.`status` = 1
GROUP BY `co`.`c_id`
HAVING sum(if(`t`.`t_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2       (---> returns 1 ) Correct !

SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`c_id`
FROM (`company` co)
JOIN `company_branch` b ON `b`.`c_id` = `co`.`id`
WHERE `co`.`status` = 1
GROUP BY `co`.`id`
HAVING sum(if(`b`.`b_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2        (---> returns 1 ) Correct !
```

But when i try to combine them like the following it gives me an empty result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`c_id`
FROM (`company` co)
JOIN `company_branch` b ON `b`.`c_id` = `co`.`id`
JOIN `company_type` t ON `t`.`c_id` = `co`.`id`
WHERE `co`.`status` = 1
GROUP BY `co`.`id`
HAVING sum(if(`b`.`b_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2 AND sum(if(`t`.`t_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2
```

My guess is that the AND between the two conditions is the culprit !! Someone have a clue?? or a work around?

Expected result: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its PROBABLY because you are getting an inadvertant Cartesian join thus resulting in 4 records.  Two for each Branch and Type.  My guess is your counts are 4 each...   To be sure, try

```
SELECT `co`.`c_id`,
       sum(if(`b`.`b_id` in (1,2),1,0)) as BranchCount,
       sum(if(`t`.`t_id` in (1,2),1,0)) as TypeCount
   FROM (`company` co)
      JOIN `company_branch` b ON `b`.`c_id` = `co`.`id`
      JOIN `company_type` t ON `t`.`c_id` = `co`.`id`
   WHERE `co`.`status` = 1
   GROUP BY `co`.`id`
```

To fix it, I would adjust as follows:

```
select co.C_ID
   from
      company co
         join company_branch b 
            on co.id = b.c_id
           and b.b_id in ( 1, 2 )
         join company_type t 
            on co.id  = t.c_id
           and t.t_id in ( 1, 2 )
   where
      co.status = 1
   GROUP BY 
      co.id
   HAVING
           count( distinct b.b_id ) = 2
       AND count( distinct t.t_id ) = 2
```

Comment: Great, the fix does the job !! -  for now :-) -  many thanx @DRapp and all the others.  u guys are amazing

Answer (score 0):

This query should meet your requirement.Instead of specifying the filter condition in your HAVING clause first calculate the sums for each co_id and apply WHERE clause filter condition on them by using a sub-query.This should work hopefully.

```
SELECT Z.* FROM
(
SELECT `co`.`c_id`,
       sum(if(`b`.`b_id` in (1,2),1,0)) as BranchCount,
       sum(if(`t`.`t_id` in (1,2),1,0)) as TypeCount
   FROM (`company` co)
      JOIN `company_branch` b ON `b`.`c_id` = `co`.`id`
      JOIN `company_type` t ON `t`.`c_id` = `co`.`id`
   WHERE `co`.`status` = 1
   GROUP BY `co`.`id`
) Z
WHERE Z.BranchCount=2 AND Z.TypeCount=2;
```

Comment: The problem is the Cartesian result... Of which your counts in the example provided would still be 4 and 4 respectively.  It will first join to the Company Branch for the first match, then hit the company type for 2 records.  Then hit the second Branch match and re-hit the type for another 2 records.  Your query would return a false result if only one branch type, but two COMPANY TYPE records as that would result with 2 each.

Answer (score 0):

Btw query you have posted have some errors so I am trying to post correct ones so that if someone wants to try that out they can do it.
1st one:
    SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`c_id`
    FROM (`company` co)
    JOIN `company_type` t ON `t`.`c_id` = `co`.`c_id`
    GROUP BY `co`.`c_id`
    HAVING sum(if(`t`.`t_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2
2nd one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`c_id`
FROM (`company` co)
JOIN `company_branch` b ON `b`.`c_id` = `co`.`c_id`
GROUP BY `co`.`c_id`
HAVING sum(if(`b`.`b_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2
```

I have excluded status column as I did not took that in my table structure.

Now I am not sure what is your business logic but I am putting up your final SQL like following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`c_id`,sum(if(`cb`.`b_id` in (1,2),1,0)) cb_sum,sum(if(`ct`.`t_id` in (1,2),1,0)) ct_sum
FROM (`company` co)
LEFT JOIN `company_branch` cb ON `cb`.`b_id` = `co`.`c_id`
LEFT JOIN `company_type` ct ON `ct`.`t_id` = `co`.`c_id`
GROUP BY `co`.`c_id`
HAVING sum(if(`cb`.`b_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2 AND sum(if(`ct`.`t_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2
```

Now if you run that SQL w/o HAVING clause you should see output like below:

```
c_id      cb_sum       ct_sum
1         4            4
2         1            1
```

So if you change your condition to "> 2" instead of "= 2" you should get what you want but the other option is that you use UNION to combine your result set as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`c_id`
FROM (`company` co)
JOIN `company_type` t ON `t`.`c_id` = `co`.`c_id`
GROUP BY `co`.`c_id`
HAVING sum(if(`t`.`t_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT `co`.`c_id`
FROM (`company` co)
JOIN `company_branch` b ON `b`.`c_id` = `co`.`c_id`
GROUP BY `co`.`c_id`
HAVING sum(if(`b`.`b_id` in (1,2),1,0)) = 2
```